# Plotting Sound using android plot

Tags: android, androidplot

How can I plot the audio data using android plot. It's like the sound against time like we do in equalizer . Simplest example is the audacity tool which plots the sound against time.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this [quick start guide from AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/) and from hear adapt your graph to the data given from your audio.

Without more information or you giving a start of what you have accomplished, there is not much more information I can give you.